# Using a scalar function in insert statement causes an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, function

When I execute the below query I get follow exception:

> Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate “dbo.GET_Vendor_Order_DeductionAmount”, or the name is
>   ambiguous

My SQL:

```
string strinsert5 = "INSERT INTO VendorWallet(
  VendorID, 
  Amount, 
  WalletTransactionTypeID, 
  Status, 
  DateAdded, 
  OrderID, 
  OrderDeductedAmount,
  ClosingBalance
) values (
  @VendorID,
  @Amount,
  @WalletTransactionTypeID,
  @Status,
  getdate(),
  @OrderID, 
  dbo.[GET_Vendor_Order_DeductionAmount] (@VendorID, " + OperatorID + ",@Amount), 
  dbo.GET_Wallet_Amount(@VendorID)+@Amount)";
```

please help me.

Comment: @JamesZ yes its exist.and its scalar function

Comment: @JamesZ yes its executed in management studio

Comment: @JamesZ yes.same databse I am using

Comment: Please include the function code into the question (not comments)

Comment: Have you tested by inserting hardcoded data into the OrderDeductedAmount and ClosingBalance columns to rule out buried issues in the functions.  Have you tried being more explicit such as [DatabaseName].dbo.[GET_Vendor_Order_DeductionAmount]?

Answer (score 0):

Why is this all in a string like this? Why is everything parameterized EXCEPT OperatorID? There is a lot of code smell in the very short amount of code posted. However, you can make this work by simply using a select instead of a values list. I would urge you to properly parameterize everything instead of most of this though.

```
string strinsert5 = "INSERT INTO VendorWallet(
  VendorID, 
  Amount, 
  WalletTransactionTypeID, 
  Status, 
  DateAdded, 
  OrderID, 
  OrderDeductedAmount,
  ClosingBalance
) 
SELECT 
  @VendorID,
  @Amount,
  @WalletTransactionTypeID,
  @Status,
  getdate(),
  @OrderID, 
  dbo.[GET_Vendor_Order_DeductionAmount] (@VendorID, " + OperatorID + ",@Amount), 
  dbo.GET_Wallet_Amount(@VendorID)+@Amount";
```